# Did I delete some important files using "os" and "shutil"?

Tags: python, windows, operating-system

I used a function to delete files that I found here in Stack Overflow for python

```
varpath = 'C:/Users/emili/Desktop/Nueva carpeta (7)/jeje'

print('Desea vaciar carpeta'+nameimg+'?\n')
print('Escriba Si o No\n')
if( input() == 'si'):
  print('Vaciando carpeta\n')
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(varpath):
    for f in files:
        os.unlink(os.path.join(root, f))
    for d in dirs:
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, d))
```

when I executed the code none of the files were being deleted so I stopped the execution using Ctrl+C and IT appeared that what you see in the cmd (see the picture below)...

I'm not sure if I deleted some important files or what this means so I hope someone can explain what that code did because it didn't delete anything in the "varpath".

[image]

I looked the Recycle Bin by the way and there was nothing there

Comment: Files deleted with Python commands do not go to the recycle bin. They are deleted directly.

Comment: @KlausD. yeah I didn't know that but I googled about it... I just wrote it anyways in case someone suggested to look the recycle bin, thanks!

Comment: You can easily restore deleted files until those specific addresses have been written over. I normally use [Recuva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recuva) for this, but there's plenty of other un-delete software available.

Comment: @pavel Advising one particular commercial product especially when there are many outside with the same purpose might be considered SPAM on Stack Overflow. Be careful with that!

Comment: @KlausD., I did specifically mention that there are many available tools and I didn't even link to a program website, but to a Wikipedia page from where Emili can go down the link and have a look at the list of other undelete software.

Comment: @pavel Im going to try any of those softwares but the thing is that Im not even sure if that function deleted something from a path different from "varpath" (I only saw what appeared in the cmd) but anyways Im going to try, thx for the recommendation

Comment: You have some library loaded that depends on a Fortran runtime library (forrtl), which sets a Ctrl+C handler that prints this useless, annoying message.

Comment: The code doesn't look to be deleting anything critical to the OS. It's a way to delete the contents of "jeje" without deleting "jeje" itself. If you want to also delete the "jeje" directory, just use `shutil.rmtree(varpath)`. Note that if there are any symlink directories present, they simply get unlinked without following them. And, in Python 3.8+ it's also smart about not following mountpoints (aka junctions) in Windows -- whereas in Unix if there are mountpoints and bind mountpoints in the tree it could be an unmitigated disaster that fails and leaves a broken mess.

Answer (score 1):

Files deleted with Python are deleted forever. Double check before you run those commands.

*Will delete any file, as long as the file exists*

```py
os.unlink(f)
```

*Will delete any folder and its contents*

```py
shutil.rmtree(d)
```

Comment: yes the problem is that the function didn't delete any of the files in the "varpath " so after a while processing I stopped the code and showed what I posted in the cmd, but I'm not sure if it deleted something from a different place and if it did delete something why it was...

Comment: Well in that case, you might want to look for software to detect the recently deleted files. It's not a programming question anymore. There's no easy way to do that with Python as far as I know.